# attach a loading component on submit using react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, formik

I have a work around that I have been trying to attach a loader or progress bar component after clicking the submit form. I have the loading declared in redux initial state but don't know how to proceed from here.

Yes, I know how to attach the loading component while fetching data from an API using GET request but don't know how to utilize with POST request. So, the form should load a component which clicking to submit and then it will send the data to the store.

Following is the sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-lewin-bp3w6?file=/src/Form.jsx

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an additional action `startLoading` that you can dispatch before the API call:

```
export const START_LOADING = "START_LOADING";
```

```
export const startLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: START_LOADING
  };
};
```

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case START_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case ADD_USERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [...state.users, action.payload],
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then in your `onSubmit` you can do:

```
props.startLoading();
props.addUsers(values);
```

Comment: thanks for the tips definitely, I will give it a try. it seems like that the loader will always load while onSubmit, would it be possible to attach the loader if the loading time takes more than 10sec or something. probably we should use some conditional rendering of props.startLoading()...

Comment: also, how to render the actual loading component in the form component?

Comment: To conditionally render the actual component, do something like `{loading && (<LoadingComponent />)}`